# Generic Search for any Django Model

Tags: django

There are several libraries which enable you to do fancy pagination of django queryset.

See this grid: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/pagination/

I have not look at all libraries, but the one I saw needed a queryset as input.

I search a solution for the step before this:

How to get to the queryset?

I search a library which translates request.GET to a queryset filter.

Example: You want to show the users (model User) with a generic interface.

AFAIK this could be solved without coding, just configuring should be enough.

```
http:///mydjangopage.example.com/query?username=foo&date_joined__gt=2017-01-01
```

The library should take request.GET and the django.contrib.auth.models.User model. The result should be a queryset. The nice double underscore feature for filter should be supported, too.

This queryset can be passed to one of above pagination libraries.

Of course autorization needs to handled somehow

License: Only open source software can be used here.

Please ask, if you don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filter

> Django-filter is a reusable Django application allowing users to declaratively add dynamic QuerySet filtering from URL parameters.

There is even a matching topic on djangopackages: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/filters/

Thanks to Melvyn Sopacua (on django-user mailinglist)